# How can I close a browser tab knowing the process ID?

Tags: unix, browser

I have a process that adds tabs to Vivaldi (or any browser): one to an external url and one to a local html file. I am able to identify the process IDs associated with each tab.

I want to be able to close the tabs. I have tried *kill <id>*. That clears the page of the local file, but the tab is still there and can be reloaded if I refresh the page. *kill* has no effect on the tab associated with the external url.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing processes is the wrong approach here anyway because apart from causing unexpected termination and not orderly closing, nothing guarantees each tab to live its own process. You may have both of them living in the same process, or sharing a process with other, unrelated tabs. Bottom line, it's not going to work or at least it'll work only sometimes and cause collateral damage. ([Others asked for such a way before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858079/close-specific-website-with-stop-process-in-powershell))

My suggestion would be a browser extension that uses [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging). You could then ask it via the native messaging function to close certain tabs for you, using the [officially supported tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) that the browser exposes to extensions.

(These links are to the Chrome extension docs, but Vivaldi is Chromium-based as well and supports the same APIs.)

---

**Alternative idea that works without an extension:**

Tabs opened through the command line behave as if they were opened by a script of the same origin, insofar that the website in them is able to call `window.close()`. So depending on your use case, maybe you can arrange for the website in the tab to close the tab by itself.

If one of them is "external" in such a way that you can't control its contents, then you could instead have one tab open the other one through JavaScript, because then the first tab can close the second tab using `close` as well.

If you need a way to communicate to the website running in your tab(s) that you want it to close itself, you could also do something like starting a local server at a random unused port and passing the port into the website via a URL parameter<sup>1</sup>, and stopping the server when you want to close the tab. Then, inside your website you would regularly poll the local server URL using AJAX and close the tab when it fails<sup>2</sup>. (Remember to return CORS headers for this to work.)

This is just one of several possible ways, and yes it is a bit "hacky" - so I'm open to suggestions on how to improve on this idea.

---

Another alternative (which may or may not fit to your use case): Instead of opening a tab, you could open a separate popup window for each website using `--app` in the command line before the URL. Then you could find the corresponding window by checking what is the newest window with a matching title, and you could close it programmatically (check out `xdotool` and `xwininfo`).

---

<sub>**1:** Why not a fixed port number? Because you can't control whether something else is already listening on that port on the user's machine.</sub>

<sub>**2:** Why not the other way round, starting the server in order to close the tab? Because then you would have to wait to ensure that the website noticed that you started the server, and if you would stop the server too early then the tab would never close, so it's extra effort and an extra possible failure point, for example if there is high CPU usage at the moment or Vivaldi put the tab into sleep mode in the background. Additionally, with my method, killing your "manager" process would then also cause the tab to close instead of leaving it sticking around. And, finally, you don't want another process to interfere with your communication by opening a server on the same port that you chose before you do so, so it'll be best to open the server right away and not only once you want the tab to close.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer - i learnt a lot. I think in my case I'm going to take the new window approach

Comment: Note that the `--app` argument is specific to the Chromium family of browsers, while the self-closing tab idea should work truly universally (unless it's some special browser that disallows it).